# Code to enable or disable an ActiveX ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with some code that actually works to enable and disable an ActiveX ComboBox. Having tried the code below and it is not working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("R2").Value = True Then ComboBox1.Enabled = True
    If Range("R2").Value = False Then ComboBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: This appears to work when I test it...

Comment: I think it is helpful if the OP elaborates on `not working` part :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("R2"), Range(Target.address)) Is Nothing Then
        If UCase(Range("R2").Value) = "TRUE" Then ComboBox1.Enabled = True
        If UCase(Range("R2").Value) = "FALSE" Then ComboBox1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That restricts the event handler to only range `"R2"`, but otherwise I don't see how this differs from OP's approach. FWIW, I don't see any problems with OP's original code...

Comment: Changed the comparison to a string comparison instead of Boolean.

Comment: Does that make a difference? It doesn't for me. OP's code works either way.

Comment: Mind if I make a small revision to tidy up your answer? Instead of two if-then statements, you can simply use the boolean expression: `ComboBox1.Enabled = CBool(Range("R2").Value)`.

Comment: All your help and advise has been most welcome but I have found that if I remove my code for the combobox all your codes work. When the code for the combobox is put back in ALL your codes stop working  so I have had to think of another way round my problem. Thanks for all your time